# jquery.ui.all couldnt be found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-rails

I am new to Ruby on rails, and my task is to refactor some code in an already existing app, so am dealing with code that I did not write. Anyway, the problem is that when I try to run a specific page the error "couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.all', the gemfile contains :gem 'jquery-rails' and gem 'jquery-ui-rails' and my application.js and .css manifest files contains "require jquery.ui.all" but the error keeps appearing. I am using:

rails (4.0.3)
jquery-rails (3.1.4)
jquery-ui-rails (5.0.5)

Those are my manifest files:

Application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require analytics
```

Application.css.scss:

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree
*/

//= require jquery-ui
```

The error is: `couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.all' (in /home/haytham/Desktop/LadyPool/com.emiketic-services.rails.flp/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:16)`

Comment: Your file would be jquery.ui and not jquery.ui.all if strictly going by the gem.  If you check your vendor assests folder and dont see a jquery.ui.all.js file then you should remove the .all

Comment: okay thank you , i will give it a try and see if your suggestion will solve the problem am stuck in this error from 5 days. @ bkunzi01

Comment: It did not work :((  this line of code is causing the error :                                 " <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => false%>"

Comment: Rather than posting individual lines of code, a larger snippet might be helpful to provide some context for better answers.

Comment: @eclarkso i've edited my post.